# How to do a basic drag and drop in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

i have a `code for basic drag and drop`. using allow drop(), drag(ev), and drop (ev).

Im planning to do the do the same in `angular js`. so that my `spa` will work fine..

**How to build the foundation structure for drag and drop in angular js.**

im trying to upgrade myself to frameworks..i have some `basic` knowlege of angular js.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="300" height="69">
```

Comment: For that you have to write directive or else you can also use ready plugins

Comment: @mayank-vadiya  a little more information will be really greatfull

Comment: Please create basic snippet then we can help  you. Or else you have to learn about how create directive in angular from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive here